# How do you sort tokens within a line

Tags: sorting

Sorting lines in Emacs is fairly straightforward with `sort-lines`.

However, how do I sort within a line? For example: `John Ringo Paul George` ->  `George John Paul Ringo`

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Answer (score 2):

Evaluate the following form (or put it into your `.emacs`):

```lisp
(defun your/sort-line ()
  "Sort the current line as you wish."
  (interactive "*")  ; Complain if buffer is read-only.
  (insert (mapconcat #'identity
                     (sort (split-string (prog1 (buffer-substring-no-properties (line-beginning-position) (line-end-position))
                                           (delete-line)))
                           #'string<)
                     "\s")))
```

Type `M-x your/sort-line` when the cursor is at the line you want to sort.

Comment: Why redefine `sort-line` for this, instead of defining a new command, `my-sort-line`?

Comment: @Drew: "*Why redefine `sort-line` for this*" -- My Emacs doesn't have a function named `sort-line`.

Comment: @Drew: OK, anyway, adding a prefix is a good idea. I will do that.

Answer (score 1):

There are several sorting commands, and some let you specify how you want "fields" to be defined, and they sort fields. See, for example, `sort(-regexp)-fields` and `sort-numeric-fields`, and maybe even `sort-columns`, depending on what you need.

See the Elisp manual, node [Sorting](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Sorting.html).

Comment: I like the idea of using an existing built-in command, but it’s not clear to be from the linked documentation how to sort all tokens on a single line 